Can't change String-Length Limit on Wikibase Labels
For a local Mediawiki with a Wikibase Extension I want to adjust the string length limit.
What I already did:
I adjusted the  legth in the LocalSettings.php:
$wgWBRepoSettings['string-limits'] = ['multilang' => ['lenght' => 500,],];

I altered the Database:
ALTER TABLE `page` MODIFY `page_title` VARCHAR(500);

And I ran all maintanance scripts.
When I try to make new labels the error message is still, that the limit to the label is 250 - the standard.
UPDATE:
I now found, that with the wikibase extension the lable of the entities  ist not in the page-Table but rather in the wbt_text Table under the wbx_text Field. I changed the varbinary Limit here, ran the maintanance scripts but it still does not work.
Any ideas how to change that?

it should be something like this: in your LocalSettings.php
$wgWBRepoSettings['maxLabelLength'] = 512;

